# Should contractions be used with first names?

Tags: names, contractions

I understand that the apostrophe character ' is used to indicate missing characters, e.g. it's => It is.  It is commonplace to use contractions in surnames, such as O'Reilly (of), or D'Artagnan (De), but I don't recall ever seeing contractions used in first names.

Is it correct to use 'Becca for Rebecca, or 'Tori for Victoria?  Or is it just that people are lazy and tend not to use apostrophes as the first character of a word?

Comment: Are you specifically asking about writing names down?

Comment: *I don't recall ever seeing contractions used in first names.* Not familiar, then, with *St John* as a first name ?

Comment: What you're talking about are "nicknames".  These are shortened versions that friends use.

Comment: As noted, to not consider nicknames to be contractions.  But you could try Daniel -> Dan'l (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_Dan%27l_Boone )

Comment: St John as a first name is indeed new to me, thanks! :-)

Comment: @HotLicks - It's not only friends that use the shortened forms, some people go by the shorter form of their name in all contexts, in some cases from day one when the parents put "Anthony" on the official paperwork but only ever say "Tony".

Comment: **O'** is not a contraction of "of". It is the way the English wrote **Ó** which is part of many Irish surnames. Irish has accents, but English has almost none, so when typesetting names like "Ó Briain" it changed to "O'Brien".

Answer (score 3):

We do not really have contractions in names. O'Reilly may have its roots in meaning "of the Reilly clan" but Mr. O'Reilly's last name is O'Reilly, not Reilly. Similarly, you should not be shortening people's first names unless you know that's what they want to be called. So if Rebecca introduces herself as Rebecca, you should call her that. If she introduces herself as Becca and doesn't use her fullname, then you may call her that.

Comment: ...and if she introduces herself as Becca don't write her name as 'Becca.

Comment: Yes, it's the written form I'm concerned with:-)  Obviously you might verbally meet Becca and not know whether she writes it as 'Becca or not!  As far as I can see, the situation is the same as refrigerator and telephone; technically those should be written as 'fridge and 'phone, but nobody does so.

Answer (score 2):

Apostrophes are typically not used in *nicknames*, because many nicknames do not have an obvious position for the apostrophe. Because many do not, it would be unusual to add it for the ones that make sense, instead of just writing the name as though it's the complete name. Here are some examples of nicknames that wouldn't make sense with an apostrophe:

> Rebecca -> Becky
>   Richard -> Dick
>   Robert -> Bobby
>   Katrina -> Kate

It's also the case sometimes that someone's full name *is* the shortened name. For instance, it's impossible to know if someone that introduces themselves as "Bob" was given a longer name at birth, or if that's the complete name. Best to just use the name as it's introduced to you.

Comment: Giving children birth names that can also be to nicknames is not a new thing. In 1977 I registered my daughter's birth with Betty as her middle name, and the registrar said "Do you mean Elizabeth?" I said "No, Betty" and that's what is written on her birth certificate.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Absolutely. I didn't mean to imply that it was new. Cheers.

Comment: I don't think shortened forenames have ever been written with apostrophes. They are just seen as nicknames, and, as Ian says, many traditional nicknames like Dick and Kate were not actually part of the full name. (Kate is usually from _Katherine_, as in my case.)  Another type of abbreviated name, _Wm., Chas._ and the like, was used _in writing_ when all documents had to be hand-written.